# TsLint: Code documentation (comments) force to finish width dot ('.')

Tags: javascript, typescript, documentation, tslint, code-documentation

How can I configure my TsLint to force all comments finishes with a dot like the following example:

```
/**
 * Defines the logo width in pixels.
 */
@Input()
width: string;
```

Follows my TsLint configuration:

```
{
  "extends": "tslint:recommended",
  "rules": {
    "array-type": false,
    "arrow-parens": false,
    "deprecation": {
      "severity": "warning"
    },
    "component-class-suffix": true,
    "contextual-lifecycle": true,
    "directive-class-suffix": true,
    "directive-selector": [
      true,
      "attribute",
      "pri",
      "camelCase"
    ],
    "component-selector": [
      true,
      "element",
      "pri",
      "kebab-case"
    ],
    "import-blacklist": [
      true,
      "rxjs/Rx"
    ],
    "interface-name": false,
    "max-classes-per-file": false,
    "max-line-length": [
      true,
      140
    ],
    "member-access": false,
    "member-ordering": [
      true,
      {
        "order": [
          "static-field",
          "instance-field",
          "static-method",
          "instance-method"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "no-consecutive-blank-lines": false,
    "no-console": [
      true,
      "debug",
      "info",
      "time",
      "timeEnd",
      "trace"
    ],
    "no-empty": false,
    "no-inferrable-types": [
      true,
      "ignore-params"
    ],
    "no-non-null-assertion": true,
    "no-redundant-jsdoc": true,
    "no-switch-case-fall-through": true,
    "no-use-before-declare": true,
    "no-var-requires": false,
    "object-literal-key-quotes": [
      true,
      "as-needed"
    ],
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "ordered-imports": false,
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "single"
    ],
    "trailing-comma": false,
    "no-conflicting-lifecycle": true,
    "no-host-metadata-property": true,
    "no-input-rename": true,
    "no-inputs-metadata-property": true,
    "no-output-native": true,
    "no-output-on-prefix": true,
    "no-output-rename": true,
    "no-outputs-metadata-property": true,
    "template-banana-in-box": true,
    "template-no-negated-async": true,
    "use-lifecycle-interface": true,
    "use-pipe-transform-interface": true,
    "variable-name": {
      "options": [
        "allow-leading-underscore"
      ]
    }
  },
  "rulesDirectory": [
    "codelyzer"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You could write a custom rule for that. [Guide for custom rules](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/develop/custom-rules/)